# Oracle - Is it a poor security practice to grant Insert/Update/Delete/Execute to the public role?

Tags: oracle

Long story short - I'm an admin for an application, and when reviewing some of the privileges, it looks like many tables grant full privileges to the public role. We don't hand out DB accounts like candy, but still, this seems like it must be a terrible security practice. Does the vendor need a good slap upside the head?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the vendor need a good slap upside the head?

No, no-one needs "a good slap upside the head". This is physical abuse and is illegal in most (all?) jurisdictions.

Maybe instead, you should discuss with them:

- Why the permissions are granted to that role;
- Whether they can be revoked without affecting the application;
- If the permissions are necessary, whether they can be granted to a less permissive role;
- What damage to your organisation could be done by granting these privileges to public roles; and
- What you need to do to file a bug report on this matter?